# VBA (Access 2013) HTTP POST not passing arguments

Tags: php, mysql, vba, http, post

I am attempting to get my Access database written in VBA to communicate with a MySQL database on my clients website through a set of PHP web services I wrote.  I have managed to get the Access db to retrieve data from the MySQL db but can't get it to post anything.  I have narrowed the problem down to the fact that my HTTP request isn't sending the arguments I assign it.

Here are some questions and sites I have looked at already.  These were not helpful, because the majority weren't dealing with PHP and were instead looking directly at websites, or were dealing with GET rather than POST.

[Http Post not posting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196749/http-post-not-posting-data)
[excel vba http request download data from yahoo finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163560/excel-vba-http-request-download-data-from-yahoo-finance)
[VBA HTTP GET request - cookies with colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377125/vba-http-get-request-cookies-with-colons)
[Pass Parameters in VBA HTTP Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111884/pass-parameters-in-vba-http-post-request)
[Perform hidden http-request from vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254420/perform-hidden-http-request-from-vba)
[How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)
http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190759/vba-oauth2-authentication-http-get-request
[VBA ServerXMLHTTP https request with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573022/vba-serverxmlhttp-https-request-with-self-signed-certificate)
[How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)
[Sending http requests with VBA from Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119207/sending-http-requests-with-vba-from-word)  [Sending http requests with VBA from Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119207/sending-http-requests-with-vba-from-word)

My code for VBA is:

```
Dim strJSONEncodedJob As String
        strJSONEncodedJob = "[{""ExpenseID"":""" & astrExpenseIDs(intI) & "}]"
        URL = "I removed the URL when posting"
        objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        objHTTP.send (strJSONEncodedJob)
        strResponse = objHTTP.responseText
        MsgBox strResponse
```

And my PHP code is:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM tblExpenses WHERE ExpenseID=?");
$txtExpenseID = $data['ExpenseID']; 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $txtExpenseID);
$stmt->execute();

echo '{"result" : "success"}';


$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I get the success statement as a msgbox in VBA, as expected, however the record is not deleted from the MySQL db.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
When I echo $json I get the JSON encoded string, which means the arguments ARE being passed.  However, when I echo $data['ExpenseID'] I get a blank msgbox.

Comment: If you echo `$json` and `$txtExpenseID` do you see what you expect?  And I'm not a PHP person but wouldn't you populate the value of `$txtExpenseID` *before* you bind it as a parameter?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo, I will amend that.  When I echo $json, I get the json string, which I wasn't before, so that suggests that the arguments are being passed.  However I still can't get it to execute that command (delete the records in MySQL).  When I echo $data['ExpenseID'] I get nothing.

Comment: Your json-encoded object is an array containing a single object, so if you want to get at that object's properties you'd first have to index it from the array. Something like  `$txtExpenseID = $data[0]['ExpenseID'];` (again, I'm not a PHP person so just guessing the syntax)

Comment: Thank you! That indexing did it.  This problem has been killing me and you fixed it.  Thank you so much.  How do I set your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json-encoded object is an array containing a single object, so if you want to get at that object's properties you'd first have to index it from the array. Something like

```
$txtExpenseID = $data[0]['ExpenseID'];
```

(again, I'm not a PHP person so just guessing the syntax)